# grep not functioning correctly

Tags: macos, command-line, grep

I've been happily using grep for many years without any issues, but since today it quit working. During the past hour I tried this and that, but enough is enough, I'm posting the bastard here:

On the simplest command like

```
grep 'aaa' file.txt
```

I'm getting this: `grep: aaa: No such file or directory`

So `grep` does not interpret the first argument as the pattern as it should, but treats it as a path.

Please help me, I'm going crazy '-(

Comment: run `which grep` and and make sure you are running the grep you think you are.

Comment: `$ /usr/bin/grep 'aaa' libiconv.log`
 yields `grep: aaa: No such file or directory`
And 
`$ ls -al /usr/bin/grep` yields
`-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  225088 May 18  2009 /usr/bin/grep`

Comment: Works fine here. You might want to include your Mac OS version in the question.

Comment: In any case, this isn't a programming question.  Voting to migrate to Super User.

Comment: 10.6.4
Are you saying that `/usr/bin/grep 'export' ~/profile` will return a meaningful result on your machine?

Comment: what does `grep --v` return? does `cat libiconv.log | grep 'aaa'` work?

Comment: and what about just 'grep file.txt' ? (which of course normally is invalid)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had something like this in my ~/.profile:

```
export GREP_OPTIONS='--color=always'
```

But with wrong syntax. Some malformeed argument was being passed to the grep breaking everything down. Removing the line resolved the problem.

Comment: thanks, i was going crazy too. i wonder if we all copied it from the same place

Answer (score 1):

You *may* have an alias set up for grep . An example:

```
$ grep aaa qq.s

$ alias grep='grep zzz'

$ grep aaa qq.s
grep: aaa: No such file or directory
```

Comment: `$ alias` does not return anything

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. If you change the single quote to a double quote in your .bash_profile GREP_OPTIONS line, you will resolve the issue. This works:

```
 export GREP_OPTIONS="--color=auto"
```

The same export with single quotes does not work. This has to do with the way that bash interprets single quotes vs double quotes. This may provide additional guidance: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Double-Quotes

Answer (score -1):

`man grep` :-)

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/grep.1.html

Comment: could you please point me to the section that would explain this behavior?